# Read logback.xml from common library

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

I have suite of application with common logging properties . I have created a common logback.xml in the common library which is being used by suite of application . I have  some application specific logging requirement which i want to put in my specific application logback.xml .TO make sure i am using the logback.xml from common library i am using 

I have couple of problem around this .
. Am i doing it correct way .If not whats the recommended way to do it
. How to define the path to logback.xml in the common library .

Comment: If I am understand it correct, you want to modify the common logback as per your need in a specific application ? If yes then please attach something like how common logback is being used in all application ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct i want to modify the common logback as per need in my specific application . I am using

Comment: Yeah you are correct i want to modify the common logback as per need in my specific application . I am using "<include resource="Path to my common lib "/>" i am not sure how to give the path though i tried couple of way to give out the path but it didnot work properly.

Answer (score 2):

you can add following property in `application.properties` file : `logging.config`

Make sure to provide the right resource prefix. If log4j2-app1.xml lives in your classpath, you should probably use:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-app1.xml
```

you need to specify the common library path in your login-config. in your common file will have a custom file for each project so it will easy for you to manage services. if you go with a common file approach then you will face a problem in the future, if you need change for some logging config to specific project common file approach will cause issues.